# Using SQL to perform unique delete

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-delete

I have a few tables in MySQL like so:

```
A ---- A_has_B ---- B
    (many to many)  |
                    |
C ---- C_has_B-------
    (many to many)
```

I need to delete rows from B given that:

- The row to be deleted are referenced in C_has_B by C.C_ID

  - The row to be deleted are not referenced by other C.C_IDs in C_has_B
  - The row to be delete is also not referenced in A_has_B

I am able to get all the rows to be deleted referenced by C.ID using:

```
DELETE * FROM C
JOIN C_has_B
ON(C.C_ID = C_has_B.C_ID)
JOIN B
on(C_has_B.B_ID = B.B_ID)
where C.C_ID = 1;
```

I am not too sure how I can implement the last 2 conditions. Is it even possible to do this with just 1 query?

Comment: Can you clarify: You want to delete rows from B that are referenced only once in C_has_B and not referenced by A_has_B?

Comment: Yes, that's what I am attempting to do here. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to delete rows from B that are referenced only once in C_has_B and not referenced by A_has_B.

With subqueries:

```
DELETE B
FROM
    B
JOIN
    (
       -- get rows from C_has_B that reference B_ID only once
       SELECT B_ID, Count(*)
       FROM C_has_B
       GROUP BY B_ID
       HAVING Count(*) = 1
    )
    as C_has_B_once
    on (B.B_ID = C_has_B_once.B_ID)
WHERE
    -- filter to rows not referenced by A_has_B
    B.B_ID not in (
       SELECT B_ID
       FROM A_has_B
    )
```

Without subqueries:

```
DELETE B
FROM
    B
-- get rows from C_has_B that reference B_ID only once
-- (find 1 match via C_has_B1 and make sure there are no other C_IDs referencing the same B_ID via C_has_B2)
JOIN
    C_has_B as C_has_B1
    on (B.B_ID = C_has_B1.B_ID) and (A_has_B.B_ID = NULL)
LEFT JOIN
    C_has_B as C_has_B2
    on (C_has_B1.B_ID = C_has_B2.B_ID) and (C_has_B1.C_ID <> C_has_B2.C_ID)
-- filter to rows not referenced by A_has_B
LEFT JOIN
    A_has_B
    on (B.B_ID = A_has_B.B_ID) and (A_has_B.B_ID = NULL)
WHERE
    -- exclude rows that join to C_has_B2
    (C_has_B2.C_ID is NULL)
```

Comment: Is it possible to write this without subqueries?

Comment: No problem! Let me know if you run into syntax issues. I didn't actually run these queries.

Comment: Is it possible to rewrite it without the subquery that gets the rows that are only referenced once?

Comment: As an add on to this, do you think the subquery verison will perform better than the one with 4 joins and 1 subquery?

Comment: Oops, I accidentally left a subquery in that 2nd example. It's fixed so check it out now. If you still want to remove the C_has_B condition then simply remove the JOIN clause and the first LEFT JOIN clause.

Comment: It's hard for me to predict the performance of both approaches. In my experience subqueries perform well unless you're working with a lot of records (thousands or more). My guess is that these queries will both perform well with a small number of records and that the 2nd query will perform better with large sets of records.

Comment: Is there a way I can filter this by C.C_ID? Using the above, I can get rows for all of C.C_ID. I have tried joining to C and adding a WHERE clause to filter by C_ID, but I am still getting entries for unwanted C_IDs.

Comment: I have found that and (C_has_B2.C_ID is NULL) does not seem to work correctly. I have moved it into a WHERE clause, and it works. However, is there a way to get it to work in the ON clause as that seems to be more efficient?

Comment: That actually makes sense because there is another condition for C_ID in that LEFT JOIN. Moving it to the WHERE clause should not affect performance. From what I've seen, conditions perform the same in either location. I've updated the 2nd example to reflect this change.